# MVC mobile page title is changing to null/empty

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, title

I have a mobile web site used with MVC 4.0 Razor Mobile version and HTML 5. When i call a page on browser or submit form page title not shown. Also it comes in view but after 1 second, it is going to null. When clicking a url in page title is coming. How can I stop changing page title to empty?

My layout page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Title)</title>
        <meta name="description" @Html.Raw("content=\"" + ViewBag.Description + "\"") />
        <meta name="keywords" @Html.Raw("content=\"" + ViewBag.Keywords + "\"") />        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
        <script src="~/Scripts/myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="/Content/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet"/>         
    </head>
    <body>        
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="layout-page">
            <div data-role="header" >
                <h1>  
                    <a style="background:none;border:none;" href="http://m.sozcukcevir.com"><img style="height:40px;border:0" src="/Content/images/logo-mobile.png" alt="sözcük çevir" /></a> </h1>
                <a href="#right-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-btn-right">Menu</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
            <div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" data-display="push" data-position="right" data-theme="a">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                        <li><a href="http://m.sozcukcevir.com">Kelime Çeviri</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/metin-ceviri">Metin Çeviri</a></li>
                        <li data-icon="audio"><a href="#">Okunuşu Dinle</a></li>
                        <li data-icon="gear"><a href="/home/settings">Ayarlar</a></li>
                        <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Kapat</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
                <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="c">
                    <ul  data-theme="c">
                        <li data-theme="c"><a href="/" id="chat" class="@ViewBag.DictLinkClass" data-icon="search">Sözlük</a></li>
                        <li data-theme="c"><a href="/metin-ceviri" class="@ViewBag.TextLinkClass" id="email" data-icon="star">Metin Çeviri</a></li>
                        <li data-theme="c"><a href="#" id="skull" class="@ViewBag.AudioLinkClass" data-icon="audio">Dinle</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
         <script>
             $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
                 $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;               
             });
        </script>
        <!-- analytics --><!-- analytics -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Page : http://m.sozcukcevir.com

Comment: `<script>$(document).on("mobileinit", function () { $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; }); </script>` should be placed in `<head>` after jQuery.js and before jQM.js

Comment: It is not working Omar

Comment: What is not working? Ajax should be disabled if you place `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;` in head I've mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I have added <script>$(document).on("mobileinit", function () { $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; }); </script> in <head> beetween jQuery.js/JQM.js and called my page but title was changing to empty.